# Flutter:Connecting Microsoft outlook exchange server

Tags: dart, flutter, exchangewebservices

Hi there I am writing an mobile application with flutter, for authenticating I need log in to our company mail server which uses exchange service for communicating, is there any dart package for exchange service?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help https://pub.dev/packages/ews#-readme-tab- It is recently published.
Repository (GitHub) https://github.com/dmytro-glynskyi/ews

> EWS #
>
> This project is a Dart client library to access Microsoft Exchange web services. The library works against Office 365 Exchange Online as well as on-premises Exchange. By using it you can access almost all the information stored in an Office 365, Exchange Online, or Exchange Server mailbox. However, this API is in sustaining mode, the recommended access pattern for Office 365 and Exchange online data is Microsoft Graph
>
> Getting started
>
> In the library the ExchangeService class contains the methods and properties that are used to set user credentials, identify the Exchange Web Services endpoint, send and receive SOAP messages, and configure the connection with Exchange Web Services. To perform an operation by using the library, you must set up the ExchangeService class.

```
final service = ExchangeService.withVersion(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
..Url = Uri.parse("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx")
..Credentials = WebCredentials("---USER_NAME---", "---USER_PASSWORD---", "---USER_DOMAIN---");
```

Installing:

- depend

```
dependencies:
  ews: ^0.0.7
```

- get package

```
$ flutter pub get
```

> Alternatively, your editor might support pub get or flutter pub get. Check the docs for your editor to learn more.

- import it

```
import 'package:ews/ews.dart';
```